# Powershell vs C# EscapeUriString different results

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I have the following problem when using standard C# code and command:

```
Uri.EscapeUriString("[]")
```

I get :

```
"[]"
```

but when I'm using PowerShell:

```
[Uri]::EscapeUriString("[]")
```

I get

```
"%5B%5D"
```

Could someone please explain me what the differences are in those method calls?
And why am I getting different results?  How to force PowerShell to return the same results as standard c#?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be .NET version related. Your C# code probably uses a more recent version.

C#

```
// .NET 4.0
Uri.EscapeUriString("[]"); // OUTPUT: "%5B%5D"

// .NET 4.5
Uri.EscapeUriString("[]"); // OUTPUT: "[]"
```

PowerShell

```
# v5
[Uri]::EscapeUriString("[]") # OUTPUT: "%5B%5D"

# for reference
Add-Type "
using System;
namespace PowerShell
{
    public static class Uri
    {
        public static string EscapeUriString(string stringToEscape)
        {
            return System.Uri.EscapeUriString(stringToEscape);
        }
    }
}"
[PowerShell.Uri]::EscapeUriString("[]") # OUTPUT: "%5B%5D"
```

There is no "Standard C#". The solution would be to make sure both are using the same .NET version, or implement your own escape method.

Alternatively, use `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode` which seems to return `"%5B%5D"` in both cases.

**Update**

In `PowerShell Core` (which uses .NET 6+) the same example returns `[]` as expected.

Comment: Just to highlight some of my findings  the simple c# console app references assembly  System.dll v4.0.30319 and Powershell references exactly the same dll

Comment: @Yawe I made the same discovery and I'm not yet sure what's the reason. But you can execute your C# code in PowerShell (using `Add-Type`) and see it returns the same result as your PS command.

Comment: @Yawe All .NET 4+ apps use the same runtime and thus the same System.dll 4.0. I suppose the change was made in another assembly.